# How to Register Google APis project?

Tags: iphone, oauth, location, social-networking

I am trying to integrate google latitute in iphone,
1. I created a projected with google latitude service and created a client secret.
2. I am using oAuthConsumer to get Access Key as follows

```
    OAConsumer *consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey:@"App key goes here"
                                                    secret:@"client secret goes here"]; 
    OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url consumer: consumer token:token realm:nil signatureProvider: nil] autorelease];
    if (!request) return;
    [request setOAuthParameterName:@"scope" withValue:@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/latitude"];
    [request setOAuthParameterName:@"oauth_callback" withValue:@"http://someURL"];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[[OADataFetcher alloc] init] autorelease];    
    [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest: request delegate: self didFinishSelector: success didFailSelector: fail];
```

The problem is in the success delegate instead of oauth token i'm getting the respose as

```
Consumer is not registered: App-key
```

So is there a mistake in the above request,
if not how to register the google api application 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should [add a domain and register](https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageDomains)  to programmatically access Google data on behalf of your users. And in the above code the scope and oauth_callback parameter should be in the URl instead of request Header